# How to efficiently split a string into lines in J?

Tags: j

I'm trying to parse a large-ish CSV file in J, and here's the line-splitting routing that I came up with:

```
splitlines =: 3 : 0
                                     NB. y is the input string
nl_positions =. (y = (10 { a.))      NB. 1 if the character in that position is a newline, 0 otherwise
nl_idx =. (# i.@#) nl_positions      NB. A list of newline indexes in the input string
prev_idx =. (# nl_idx) {. 0 , nl_idx NB. The list above, shifted one position to the right, with 0 as the first element
result =. ''
for_i. nl_idx do.                                  NB. For each newline
    to_drop =. i_index { prev_idx                  NB. The number of characters from the start of the string to skip
    to_take =. i - to_drop                         NB. The number of characters in the current line
    result =. result , < (to_take {. to_drop }. y) NB. Take the current line, box it and add to the result
end.
)
```

It's really slow, though. The performance monitor shows that line 8 takes the longest, likely because of all the memory allocation when dropping and taking elements and extending the result list:

```
 Time (seconds)
┌────────┬────────┬─────┬─────────────────────────────────────────┐
│all     │here    │rep  │splitlines                               │
├────────┼────────┼─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┤
│0.000011│0.000011│    1│monad                                    │
│0.003776│0.003776│    1│[1] nl_positions=.(y=(10{a.))            │
│0.012429│0.012429│    1│[2] nl_idx=.(#i.@#)nl_positions          │
│0.000144│0.000144│    1│[3] prev_idx =.(#nl_idx){.0,nl_idx       │
│0.000002│0.000002│    1│[4] result=.''                           │
│0.027566│0.027566│    1│[5] for_i. nl_idx do.                    │
│0.940466│0.940466│20641│[6] to_drop=.i_index{prev_idx            │
│0.011238│0.011238│20641│[7] to_take=.i-to_drop                   │
│4.310495│4.310495│20641│[8] result=.result,<(to_take{.to_drop}.y)│
│0.006926│0.006926│20641│[9] end.                                 │
│5.313052│5.313052│    1│total monad                              │
└────────┴────────┴─────┴─────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Is there a better way to do this? 
I'm looking for a way to:

1. Slice a list without memory allocation
2. Maybe replace the whole `for` loop with one single array instruction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are currently just wanting to split a string containing multiple lines, into the separate lines. (I imagine splitting the lines into fields will be the next step at some later stage?)

The key primitive that does the heavy lifting for most of what you are wanting to do is [cut](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/semidot) (`;.`). For example:

```
   <;._2 InputString   NB. box each segment terminated by the last character in the string
   <;._1 InputString   NB. box each segment of InputString starting with the first character in the string
   cut;._2 InputString NB. box each segment of InputString separated by 1 or more spaces
```

Other related resources that you may find useful are: `splitstring`, `freads`, the [`tables/dsv`](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Addons/tables/dsv) and [`tables/csv`](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Addons/tables/csv) addons. `freads` and `splitstring` are both available in the standard library (post J6).

```
   'b' freads 'myfile.txt'  NB. returns contents of myfile.txt boxed by the last character (equivalent to <;._2 freads 'myfile.txt')
   '","' splitstring InputString  NB. boxed sub-strings of input string delimited by left argument
```

The `tables/dsv` and `tables/csv` addons can be installed using the [Package Manager](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/JAL/Package_Manager). Once installed they can be used to split lines and fields within lines as follows:

```
   require 'tables/csv'
   readcsv 'myfile.csv'
   ',' readdsv 'myfile.txt'
   TAB readdsv 'myfile.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful.

Comment: While the libraries are the way to go, since you mentioned cut (`;.`) and `TAB`, it might be nice to also include mention of `LF` and even `CR`. `a. i. TAB,LF,CR` shows that they're the ASCII characters `9 10 13`. This is useful when you don't trust the file to start or end with the character on which you want to cut: `<;._1 LF , InputString`

Comment: Yes that is useful. Note that `freads` will sort this issue for most files. It will convert to LF delimiters and ensure that there is a trailing LF.

Comment: I'm processing a very large file (~1G, 12M lines): cutting it into boxed lines (~10s), and then using a regex to extract a number from each line, and summing all those numbers.  J absolutely chokes on this.  I end up having to force quit, even though a slow lang like ruby can handle it ok.  I've tried both a `for_x` loop using a procedural approach, as well as a standard tacit J approach.  Neither works.  Any tips?

Comment: Given the cutting bit is quick, I wouldn't have thought this should be a problem. Maybe a new question with some examples of exactly what you are wanting to do would help?